# Espresso tests failing randomly, presumably a timing issue

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a few tests that only seem to fail the first time i run them, here is an example of one of them;

```
class OptionDialogTest {
    @get:Rule
    val activityScenarioRule = activityScenarioRule<MainActivity>()

    @Test
    fun optionDialogTest() {
        val selected = R.string.manage_categories
        var dialog: OptionDialog? = null
        activityScenarioRule.scenario.onActivity { activity: MainActivity? ->
            dialog = OptionDialog("test", "test", arrayOf(R.string.drawer_categories,selected), activity as Context)
            dialog!!.setConfirm { _, _ -> }
            dialog!!.show()
        }
        onView(withId(R.id.custom)).perform(click()) //this line sometimes doesn't execute causing the test to fail, presumably it doesn't execute in time.
        onView(withText(R.string.manage_categories)).inRoot(isPlatformPopup()).perform(click())
        onView(withText(R.string.Yes)).inRoot(isDialog()).perform(click())
        assertEquals(dialog!!.getSelected(), selected)
    }
    
}
```

the error android studio gives is; `Waited for the root of the view hierarchy to have window focus and not request layout for 10 seconds. If you specified a non default root matcher, it may be picking a root that never takes focus.`

my only guess is that some of the code isn't executing in an completely asyncronous fashion. I don't know if other developers experiance random test failures, or how i would go about fixing this.

any help or ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing the faulty line to `onView(withId(R.id.custom)).inRoot(isDialog()).perform(click())`? Maybe it was picking the view from the wrong root.

Comment: I haven't, but that would make sense, ill give it a go and see if it happens again.